# Can't shrink drawing when printing to smaller paper format

Tags: printing, microsoft-visio-2010

I have a Visio-drawing drawn in A3 format. Now I wish to print it on A4 format and have Visio to shrink it to fit that format. However, it still want's to print in A3 size and thus cropping the parts that don't fit.

I have set the paper and layout format to A4 and having it fit on paper but nothing seems to work. The drawing is still in A3 format.

Comment: For questions like this it will help to identify which version of Visio you are using and add screenshots of the printer settings and the page layout options.

Comment: Well, the version i thought was clear from the tag. Also, it's premium.

Comment: I didn't see the tag but it still recommend adding it to the question body or title as a convenience for other SuperUser members. In context they view this questions (mobile, etc.) they may not see the tags only the title or question body.